# Why aren't my WCF Data Services collections being listed?

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to make a simple WCF Data Service. I am able to successfully access the `scv` file but my `Cars` collection doesn't get listed. The content of my `scv` is:

```
[DataServiceKey("VIN")]
public class Car
{
    public String VIN { get; set; }
    public String Make { get; set; }
    public String Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class CarService : DataService<Car>
{
    public IQueryable<Car> Cars
    {
        get
        {
            return (new List<Car> {
                new Car { VIN = "ABC123", Make = "Ford", Model = "F-250", Year = 2000 },
                new Car { VIN = "ABC124", Make = "BMW", Model = "Z-3", Year = 2005 },
                new Car { VIN = "ABC125", Make = "Audi", Model = "TT", Year = 2008 }
            }).AsQueryable();
        }
    }

    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}
```

When access this service on the browser I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="http://localhost:60730/CarService.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

See that the collection didn't get listed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[DataServiceKey("VIN")]
public class Car
{
    public String VIN { get; set; }
    public String Make { get; set; }
    public String Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class MyContainer
{
    public IQueryable<Car> Cars
    {
        get
        {
            return (new List<Car> {
                new Car { VIN = "ABC123", Make = "Ford", Model = "F-250", Year = 2000 },
                new Car { VIN = "ABC124", Make = "BMW", Model = "Z-3", Year = 2005 },
                new Car { VIN = "ABC125", Make = "Audi", Model = "TT", Year = 2008 }
            }).AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}

public class CarService : DataService<MyContainer>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! Ladislav, You've already saved more me than once. Thank you very much. Btw, this snippet I provided is included in Microsoft Press book for MCTS 70-516. As it seems it's not correct.

Comment: I know only little bit about WCF Services but this is example of reflection provider where type passed as generic parameter to the service is browsed by reflection and searched for properties exposing `IQueryable`. So I believe the example is wrong and it will not be too big surprise. Just today I wrote [short blog post](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/07/microsoft-certification-exams-70-561-and-70-516/) about my experience with MCTS 70-516.